# Track how often comparison engines come to pick feeds

Tags: php, analytics

I submit several feed urls to search engines which they come to pick at different times of the week. Example of the feed url looks like mysite.com/feed.csv. I want to be able to track at what time of the day did the search engine fetch my feeds through the urls.

Answer (score 0):

Just check your server logs to see when the file was pinged

Answer (score 0):

I would advise looking at the web server access log filtering for requests of the URL `/feeds.csv`